Asian action movie that ends with shootout and birth
I only saw the end of the movie, but it ends with two parallel action setpieces.  In one, a guy in a gangster hat, glasses and trench-coat has a shootout with a bunch of others, possibly at an airport.  I think he's using a shotgun or an assault rifle.  At one stage he slides away from the action on his back, sliding a stupidly long way. 
In the other, a guy with long hair, possibly white or just wearing white, is protecting a heavily pregnant lady.  She goes into labour and he tries to help her, but I think he has to leave to fight the bad guys hand to hand.  I think at some stage he confronts another guy on an elevated walkway (like above a stage).   
I saw this maybe 10-15 years ago on Australian TV.  I think it was from Hong Kong or Korea.

Sounds very much like Tsui Hark's Hong Kong action movie Time and Tide from 2000. Near the end, the (long-haired) protagonist has to deliver a baby as he fights off bad guys while a guy in a gray coat with glasses and an assault rifle slides on the floor of a train station in a stand-off with a SWAT team and bad guys are thwarted on a platform above a concert. Some of the details are a tiny bit off, though (glasses guy has no hat). See if the trailer seems familiar:



